# How to use TransactionScope properly?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, transactionscope

I always want to try to use `TransactionScope` but I just can't figure out what people see about it that is useful. So let's take an example:

```
using(TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope()) {
    CallAMethodThatDoesSomeWork1();
    CallAMethodThatDoesSomeWork2();
    tran.Complete();
}
```

So the most basic question: How do I write "`CallAMethodThatDoesSomeWork1()`" so that it knows how to roll its actions back if let's say "`CallAMethodThatDoesSomeWork2()`" throws an exception?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The code within the methods you call need to be transaction aware and enlist in the active transaction. This means creating or using classes which are resource managers (see [Implement Your Own Resource Manager](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/sortinganditerating/article.php/c10993/SystemTransactions-Implement-Your-Own-Resource-Manager.htm).

You do this by implementing [IEnlistmentNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification.aspx) and enlisting in the transaction. When the transaction is completed, the transaction manager will call methods as defined on that interface so that your code can do/undo the work.

Comment: Oh, I see how to do it. Wish the MSDN page for "TransactionScope" said it -- been looking at it and completely never saw the point of TransactionScope. This is the magic interface to make it work. This makes sense!